# drupal node‘s image field do not dispaly the image

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7

The problem was appeared when I migrate my site from WindowsServer2003 to CentOS.
  There is a image field in the Node type.In the old server everything goes well,but in the CentOS the nodes' image field do not show the picture. It just show the image name as a link and click the image name I can see the picture in a new browser tab.

I know that the images have been upload in the sites/default/files. And also the permission for the directory is 777.

I google a lot but get no results.

so what cause the problem? any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Unix-based systems use different pathing syntax, so the paths for your images may not work now, under CentOS. Use a text editor's find-and-replace feature to change the paths in the database by exporting the database to a SQL file, running the find-and-replace, and then importing the file. Make sure to keep backups of everything.